# Scope with an array of items in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I am trying to create a multi-select filter for listing products available by vendors.  I have a scope in my vendor_offering's model

```
scope :by_vendor, -> (vendor_id) {where vendor_id: vendor_id}
```

How can I get the scope to allow an array of items like [1,2,3] and return items that vendors 1,2,3 have available?

Comment: your code should work.. What's the problem ?

Comment: When I run http://localhost/vendor_offerings?vendor=1,2  it is only returning vendor 1, not 1 & 2

Comment: try vendor[]=1,2 in params and controller

Comment: @Legendary where would I put that exactly? In my controller i have:
filtering_params(params).each do |key, value|
      offerings = offerings.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
    end

Comment: in head of your function do puts(params[:vendor]) and show me

Comment: @legendary Parameters: {"vendor"=>"1,2"}

Comment: @NickDelaney so try now params[:vendor].split(',').map{ |n| n.to_i }

Comment: @NickDelaney dont forget to approve ans for improving SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params[:vendor].split(',').map{ |n| n.to_i }
```

It gave you needs array with ids.